# Value of type 'MSTable?' has no member 'pullWithQuery'

Tags: swift, azure, azure-mobile-services

I tried to change client page size in Azure server
it's default is 50 and I want to make it bigger
so i use Microsoft tutorial in this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library#querying

```
var client : MSClient?
let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "AppUrl")
let table = client.tableWithName("TodoItem")
let query = table.query()
let pullSettings = MSPullSettings(pageSize: 3000)
but when I write 
table.pullWithQuery(query, queryId:nil, settings: pullSettings) { (error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("ERROR ", err)
    }
}
```

there are error "Value of type 'MSTable?' has no member 'pullWithQuery'"

what is the problem ?
is the function name changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The documentation has not been updated for current versions of Swift
   (an update request has been filed). The correct function name in modern Swift is pull rather than pullWithQuery.
2. The pullWithQuery function is on MSSyncTable, not MSTable. Pull is part of the offline sync system. The MSTable analog is read.

More details:

The SDK itself defines the function as [MSSyncTable.pullWithQuery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/blob/ff85b6c99945b5899a7b2edcc521f83c9ed99a6a/sdk/src/MSSyncTable.h), but one of the features of Swift 3.0 is that it renames Objective C methods when it projects them into Swift to remove redundant arguments from the name, so verbWithX(X) becomes just verb(with:x) and pullWithQuery (MSQuery) becomes pull(with:MSQuery).

For more information on Swift 3 changes please see https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/ . I believe this particular change is [SE-0005: Better Translation of Objective-C APIs Into Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md)

If you download the Swift quickstart from your Azure Portal then you’ll get the correct modern pattern there:

```
self.table!.pull(with: self.table?.query(), queryId: "AllRecords")
```

or with your arguments:

```
self.table!.pull(with: self.table?.query(), queryId: nil, settings: pullSettings)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help I edited it to this code 
        let table = client?.syncTable(withName: "name")
        
        let query = table?.query()
        
        let pullSettings = MSPullSettings(pageSize: 3000)
        
        table!.pull(with: table?.query(), queryId: nil, settings: pullSettings){ (error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("ERROR ", err)
            }
        }
        new error appear
        "Client must have an initialized MSSyncContext"
        please help me

Comment: Using the MSSyncTable requires that you first set up your app for offline syncing as documented at Enable offline syncing with iOS mobile apps (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data). The first thing this document covers is setting up the offline data store and initializing the syncContext. 

As with the pullWithQuery code, the documentation is not yet updated to Swift 3.0 and will need to be converted to the modern Swift syntax.

If you need help after going through this please ask your new question as its own Question